# How to install MySQL Workbench on Fedora 21

Tags: mysql, fedora

Is there an easy way to install MySQL Workbench on Fedora 21?

I could not find a RPM package and failed at compiling it from source because I am using MariaDB and therefore was unable to install mysql++-devel.

The MySQL Website only provides a RPM package for Fedora 20, which cannot be used any longer as it depends on ctemplate 2.2.

Answer (score 7):

A Fedora 21 repository has been added:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

Comment: I have to mention that although this may work, you have to give up mariadb (server and client) in favor of the community's mysql builds.

Comment: Workbench isn't included as of now.

Comment: FYI Workbench is now in there - I just installed it

Answer (score 5):

I installed the [RHEL7 package](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm) on my newly installed Fedora 21 (x86_64). Works flawlessly thus far.

Comment: Funny, this was the only way I got it installed in Fedora 21. Repo @gdlin mentions, did not appear to contain the required package.

Comment: Works for me as well. Though I had to install `tinyxml` as it didn't get pulled in as a dependency.

Comment: Same problem here as with the fc20 version: the result grid doesn't show up. It doesn't store passwords in the keychain either btw.

Comment: FWIW, there's a version for F21 in the community repo now.

Answer (score 3):

An RPM package for Fedora 21 is now available on the official downloads page:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is relevant for more than a single version of Fedora, here's a quick howto for Fedora in general, written at Fedora 28, but it should be applicable for similar versions too.

1. Install a repository from the following page: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/. It is an RPM itself, so download it and install it with `sudo dnf localinstall mysql80-community-release-fc28-1.noarch.rpm` (actual filename depends on your system; yum has been replaced with dnf in latest versions of Fedora)
2. Install MySQL Workbench: `sudo dnf install mysql-workbench`. Note that for some reason, the autocomplete of package names seems to be broken for these packages, so if you only type `dnf install mysql-` and hit `<TAB>`, it will not suggest the package. But it still works.

Comment: This worked for me, although the name of the repository RPM is now `mysql80-community-release-fc28-2.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the [older Package from Fedora 20](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25146203/dir/fedora_20/com/ctemplate-2.2-5.fc20.x86_64.rpm.html). It is not the right way, just a workaround. But i guess it is better as no mysql-workbench

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While it is possible to start mysql-workbench with the old ctemplate Version installed, data grids remain empty when executing queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [Workbench RPM for x86_64](http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/7/x86_64/mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm)
2. `sudo yum install tinyxml`

Comment: Result sets remain empty when running a query.

Answer (score 0):

I've patched `mysql-connector-c++.spec` and `mysql-workbench.spec` so you can mock both spec files for Fedora 21.

Please read the instructions in `README.rst` to build it yourself.

https://github.com/meeuw/mysql-workbench-fedora-21